# Please make my terminal behave like a word processor because I'm old and jaded

Tags: terminal, text-editing, iterm2

How do I make the terminal input behave like a multi-line word processor that lets me select text, delete some text (no hex codes), move around, then only really send it over the wire when I press Enter? Assume that I never ever SSH into anything. I don't mind installing another process on top of iTerm if it can't do this. I'm not a command-line cowboy and I never want to be. I can no longer deal with having to customise this:

[image: any problem you are trying to solve in the terminal, shouldn't be a problem be broken in the first place]

Comment: I'm afraid it may not be possible. Some programs may want to act on input before Enter is pressed, for example with (y/n) prompts. This would mess these up.

Comment: Use an actual terminal text editor, such as `nano` or `vi`, save the file as `executeThis.sh` and then run that file?

Comment: Thanks @Mokubai, that is what I'm doing a lot of the time, but 99% of my terminal calls are one-time calls; I don't actually want to save a file for it or have to think about naming the file.

Comment: Some shells like you ask for were started and abandoned. Perhaps you could look at [Xiki](http://xiki.org/), although it might have some learning curve.